IBM Z Xplore concept badge 1 VSC1 challenge
enter image description here
I am doing IBM Z Xplore course to earn badge. In the 1st challenge I have to install Zowe extension in VS code and connect my Zid. I have proceed through all the steps instructed there except one. I can't connect to USS there showing an error (as mentioned in image). And for this reason all the folder in Data Sets are empty (ig so). I have to identify a file and have to submit it which should be inside ZXP.PUBLIC.JCL folder. Please guide me to fix this issue if anyone knows.
There should be some files. Folders must not be empty.

The IBM Z XPlore platform has a discussion forum, monitored by the several thousands users that have been through the challenges. You are more like to get an informed answer  by using that forum.

You have tagged this question as "ibm-cloud" - it has no connection with the IBM Cloud - it relates to IBM zOS, and the IBM Z XPlore learning environment.

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly. See Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

You should enter a path like /z/z*
